# MVC 3 Application fails to run locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Every time I try to run my MVC 3 application I get this error

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Now I have googled and tried every solution I have tried updating Nuget packages which is the most common solution but sadly with no luck.

Has anyone had this in MVC 3? if so did they resolve it?

Comment: are you running the app in visual studio or on separate server?

Comment: @Neverever within Visual Studio

Comment: Any one come across this issue?

Comment: Try removing the reference of `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` and adding it again!

Comment: @RandomUser Nope, still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after so much googling I have found the solution.

I download Web Platform Installer and searched for MVC 3

[image]

I Choose ASP.NET MVC 3(Visual Studio 2010) clicked "Add" and then "Install" waited for it to install and powered up visual studio again opened up the project and hit run and it now works :)